# How to render different UJS actions based on the click event in Rails 4 with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ujs

I have a div and need to render different .js.erb actions based on the `clickevent` **on that div**.
For example:

- on `dblClick`, I want to render the new.js.erb
- on `click`, I want to render show.js.erb

In my asset/javascripts directory I have a **file.js.coffee**:

```
$('#myDiv').on "dblclick" ->
  $.getScript('/projects/xy/plan/new')
```

This basically works. It shows the modal in my **new.js.erb**:

```
$("#myModal").modal("show");
```

How can I make the `$.getScript` URL dynamic and include an object for the show and edit action?

**Edit:**
Rich Pecks answer seems to be correct.
Because of simplicity I just wrote `$('#myDiv').on "dblclick"`.
The full example is:

```
  $zoomcontainer = $("section").find(".parent")
  $panzoom = $zoomcontainer.find(".panzoom").panzoom(
    $zoomIn: $zoomcontainer.find(".zoom-in")
    $zoomOut: $zoomcontainer.find(".zoom-out")
    $zoomRange: $zoomcontainer.find(".zoom-range")
    $reset: $zoomcontainer.find(".reset")
  ).on("dblclick", (e) ->
```

How should I put my data attributes in the HTML?

This is my basic HTML structure:

```
<section>
  <div class="parent" data-project_id="<%= @project.id %>" data-plan_id="<%= @plan.id %>">
    <input type="range" class="zoom-range" />
    <div id="plan" class="panzoom" style="background: url('<%= @plan.asset.url %>') no-repeat;>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you could use a different event handler:

```
var plan_url = "/projects/xy/plan";

$('#myDiv').on "dblclick" ->
  $.getScript(plan_url + '/new')

$('#myDiv').on "click" ->
  $.getScript(plan_url + '/show')
```

Although this seems too simple to be what you're asking for

---

**Dynamic**

If you're looking to handle dynamic routes, you'll need to be able to pass the various object variables through your HTML (JS can't read Rails variables)

You'd have to do something like this:

```
#app/views/posts/show.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, class: "your_class", data: {project_id: @post.project_id, plan_id: @post.plan_id} do -%>
    Your div
<% end -%>

#-> <div class="your_class" data-project_id="15" data-plan_id="6">Your Div</div>
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
   #app/assets/javascripts/application.js
   $('#myDiv').on "dblclick" ->
       project = $(this).data("project_id")
       plan = $(this).data("plan_id")

       $.getScript('/projects/' + project + '/plan/' + plan)
```

Comment: Thats too simple because the URL is dynamic: `/projects/:project_id/plans/:plan_id`

Comment: Okay, you'd need to include the variable in your HTML somewhere (let me update answer)

Comment: Your answer seems to be correct. Unfortunately, if I do a `console.log project` (or plan) I get an undefined. I think it's because it's not just a simple div, that I want to click on. I extended my question.

Comment: The process I put forward will give you access to the data to make your JS routes dynamic - obviously getting that to work will depend on how we can select the div

Comment: Added more infos. Not sure, whether I should ask new question, because  I thinks you answered the first one...

Comment: I would ask a new question being honest -- it will give clearer context, and therefore receive more accurate answers :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46420/discussion-between-kentucky-and-rich-peck)